# Does SystemVerilog support downcasting?

Tags: casting, system-verilog

Does SystemVerilog support downcasting (casting a base object to a derived object)? If so, how?

The following downcast example does not work:

```
class base;
  int a = 5;
endclass

class extend extends base;
  int b = 1;
endclass

module test;

  initial begin
    base m_base;
    extend m_extend;

    m_base = new();
    m_extend = new();
    $cast(m_extend, m_base);
    $display(m_extend.a);
  end
endmodule
```

Modify and rerun the example on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/581

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can downcast. Your example is the correct syntax, and it actually does compile. However you are getting a runtime error because the cast fails.

The cast in you example is failing because you can only successfully downcast if the handle to the base object is actual referencing an object of the derived type.  You can call `$cast` as a function and it will return a boolean indicating whether the cast was successful or not.

Here is an example:

```
class animal;
  function void eat();
  endfunction
endclass

class dog extends animal;
  function void bark();
    $display("woof");
  endfunction
endclass

class cat extends animal;
  function void meow();
    $display("meow");
  endfunction
endclass

module test;

  initial begin
    dog a_dog = new();
    cat a_cat = new();

    animal animals[$];
    animals.push_back(a_dog);
    animals.push_back(a_cat);

    foreach (animals[i]) begin
      dog another_dog;
      animals[i].eat();
      if ($cast(another_dog, animals[i])) begin
        $display("Found a dog!");
        another_dog.bark();
      end
    end

  end
endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
# Found a dog!
# woof
```

See http://www.edaplayground.com/s/474/586

Comment: So the downcast works only if the source object was first upcast.

Comment: Yes for the most part. It needn't be a result of an explicit upcast, but you do need to have the base-type reference pointing to an object of the derived type.

Answer (score 4):

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 8.16 "Casting" states:

> It is always legal to assign an expression of subclass type to a variable of a class type higher in the inheritance tree (a superclass or ancestor of the expression type). It shall be illegal to directly assign a variable of a superclass type to a variable of one of its subclass types. However, `$cast` may be used to assign a superclass handle to a variable of a subclass type provided the superclass handle refers to an object that is assignment compatible with the subclass variable.

The following cast failes because a superclass object not be read as an childclass.

```
m_base = new();
$cast(m_extend, m_base); // destination type != source object type
```

To cast correctly the object of the source handle must be compatible with the destination typetypes must be comparable:

```
m_extend = new();
m_base = m_extend;
$cast(m_extend, m_base); // destination type == source object type
```

Downcasting can work through levels of inheritance. The following example demonstrates a base class handle pointing a grandchild object being casted to the extend class (the grandchild object's parent class):

```
class ext_more extends extend;
  int c;
endclass
initial begin
  base m_base;
  extend m_extend;
  ext_more m_ext_more;

  m_ext_more = new();
  m_base = m_ext_more;
  $cast(m_extend, m_base); // legal, casting a subclass object to a parent handle
  $display(m_extend.a);
end
```

Here are some working example: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/587

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, you are nowhere downcasted, you just use the `$cast` to check if classes are compatible or not. If yes,  print that particular class (DOG in your case) is found.

In you `$cast` function first parameter (destination) you are taking `another_dog` as a child class and in the second parameter (source) you are picking from queues that is again queues of child classes